# Rails PostgreSQL select all messages in a ticket that last message was by admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a ticket system, and I added a filter option to fetch all tickets, that were un-answered.

*An un-answered ticket is a ticket that is open and that the last message was posted by a non-admin user, means the user could have posted a message after that an admin replied, so it becomes un-answered again, awaiting for response.*

Now my I have `tickets` model which `has_many` `messages` and each message belongs to `user`

Now if you break it down to steps, you'd do this:

1. Fetch all tickets that have the status "open" `(tickets.status = 'open')`
2. Loop through all tickets ticket -> I
3. Get the messages array from ticket
4. Grab the last message from that ticket (ordered by `created_at`)
5. Grab the `user_id` from that last message, and check if that user is `users.admin = false`
6. If the user is not admin, push that ticket into the unanswered tickets array.

The following steps is how I would do it in another language besides ruby, but I prefer to do it all in one query when using ruby, because if I will push the un-answered tickets into a new array, I will no longer have an `ActiveRecords` object that lists all of these tickets, and therefore I cannot use `gems` like `will_paginate` on it because array is not an active records.

So I gave one go at doing that query, and seems like it just works wrong, I don't know to explain because I totally got lost in it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tickets.id FROM tickets 
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.commentable_id = tickets.id 
LEFT JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id 
WHERE (SELECT users.admin FROM messages WHERE messages.commentable_id = tickets.id AND messages.user_id = users.id ORDER BY messages.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) = false
```

*I would love to get some help and hints!*

Comment: It would be easier to add "unanswered" flag to ticket, set it to ```true``` when user posts new message and to ```false``` when admin posts answer. Very simple query

Comment: True that, but I still would like to see how a complex query like this looks like :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that would work:

```
Ticket.where(status: 'open').
  joins(messages: :user).
  group('messages.ticket_id').
  having('messages.created_at = MAX(messages.created_at) AND users.admin = "f"')
```